# width is fit 100% not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a HTML page where I added body as 100% But when I am minimizing browser and scrolling body still remain in the same sate where it was minimized.
[image]

Comment: Please add relevant code and related CSS

Comment: post your code its very easy to answer your question

Comment: post your html and css source, so i help easily to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am sure try this,

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    min-width: 1140px; /* this is the important part*/
}
```

Comment: why this should be 1140px

Comment: I am sure you have get idea on this sites http://www.1140px.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this? I think your header div also need this css.

```
html, body {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#yourHeader{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    /*
    height:150px; bla bla...
    */
}
```